# How to add legend to matplolib 3D voxels plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

Is there a chance to add a legend to the plot which has been shown below? And if there is a possibility I would like to use HTML colors in it. 
[image: 3D voxels plot]
Appreciate for your help, lads.

Comment: Please include your code.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [matplotlib.patches](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/patches_api.html?highlight=matplotlib%20patches#module-matplotlib.patches).

Here is the [examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/94460/matplotlib.patches.Patch).